# Mysql select distinct rows in one table based on rows of another

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have two tables(Friends and News_Feed). I need to retrieve the most recent rows(highest id) from the News_Feed table. The catch is that I only want to select rows in the News_Feed table that pertain to either of the two columns in the Friends table. I also need to order by News_Feed.id, so creating two queries(such as first selecting my friends, and then looping into a News_Feed query) will not work. Tables are set up as follows:

**-Friends-**
id
user
user_friending

**News_Feed**
id
pertaining_user
action
orig_comment

My current, unworking query, is...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM News_Feed WHERE pertaining_user=(SELECT user FROM Friends WHERE user_friending='37' AND is_confirmed='1' UNION SELECT user_friending FROM Friends WHERE user='37' AND is_confirmed='1') AND orig_comment='0' ORDER BY id DESC")or die(mysql_error());
while($row_news = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

This returns subquery returns more than one row error, which I understand. There must be way though to do this.

Comment: There are three columns in the friends table ??

Comment: Yes. One only three columns. The table is simply there to show the friend relationshop of users

Comment: @dminicrick1 - Then where is `is_confirmed` coming from?

Comment: You know what, is_confirmed is another row in that table. I'm sorry, still asleep I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
select
    *
from
    News_Feed f
where
    exists (
        select
            1
        from
            friends u
        where
            (u.user = f.pertaining_user and u.user_friending = '37')
            or (u.user_friending = f.pertaining_user and u.user = '37')
            and u.is_confirmed = 1
    )
order by
    f.id desc
```

This will be much faster than trying to do an `in` with a `union`. It does a semi-join and throws out invalid rows immediately.

Comment: Eric, I tried your query and cannot get it to work. It is only selecting one user(37) and displaying based on that. I was actually looking for the inverse. Konerak's solution works great, but it is not as efficient as it could be. Any ideas on how to adapt your's to work as his does?

Comment: I edited mine for you--it was just getting a `pertaining_user` of `37` at first. Now, it looks to find any `friends` row with a `user` or `user_friending` equal to `37`, and then returns if either of those columns match the `pertaining_user`.

Comment: Still not working properly. It is still only retrieving News_Feed items that pertain to user 37, when it should be retrieving News_Feed items that pertain to all of user 37's friends from the Friends table.(pulling hair out)

Comment: @dminicrick1 - Try that. It only pulls the `news_feed` if the pertaining_user is a friend of `37`, rather than is `37`, as well.

Comment: You're a life saver...That's it!! It seems so obvious now haha....except that I have not used the EXISTS clause until now. +++++++

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the `IN` keyword.

```
SELECT * 
FROM News_Feed 
WHERE pertaining_user IN 
 (
 SELECT user 
 FROM Friends 
 WHERE user_friending='37' 
 AND is_confirmed='1' 
UNION 
 SELECT user_friending 
 FROM Friends 
 WHERE user='37' 
 AND is_confirmed='1') 
AND orig_comment='0' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```